# Rails route globbing vs. escaping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I'm trying do something like this:

```
map.goto '/g/*extra', :controller => 'goto', :action => :show
```

Where extra is a path component, e.g.:

```
redirect_to goto_url( employee_path(employee) )
```

What I **get** is:

```
http:://www.example.com/g/%2Femployee%2F123
```

What I **want** is:

```
http:://www.example.com/g/employee/123
```

So my question is: although all of this works fine, is there any way to suppress parameter escaping for Rails route params, particularly a globbed param?

Answer (score 0):

The url helper for a globbed route like that takes an array of path components, so you'll probably be able to get around that by doing `goto_url( employee_path(employee).split('/') )`

Comment: Thanks! , goto_url + employee_path(...) - but both of these approaches look wrong to me, so I'm hoping something more like:

map.goto '/g/*extra', :controller => 'goto, :action  => :show, :escape => false